# how to define a label in a new environment?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, environments

I would like to define a new environment for writing exercices. Moreover, I would like to use `\ref` and `\nameref` (with `hyperref` package) to build a table of exercise numbers and names.
I wrote the following file. The `\ref` works well (it gives me the number of the exercise) but `\nameref` gives me the name of the section instead of the name of the name of the exercise

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exo}
\newenvironment{exo}[1]%
{\refstepcounter{exo}\vspace{0.5cm}\noindent
{\begin{large}\bfseries{Exercice \theexo~: #1} \end{large}} \par}
{\par\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}
A small example

\section{First degree}
\begin{exo}{First degree equation}\label{exo:first_degree}
Solve the equation~:\[ x+7 = -9 \: . \]
\end{exo}

\section{Second degree}
A little harder\ldots

\begin{exo}{Second degree equation}\label{exo:second_degree}
solve the equation~:\[ x^2 - 2x -3 =0 \: . \]
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{Another exercise}\label{exo:other_exercise}
solve this equation:\[ -3x^2 +7x-64=0 \: .\]
\end{exo}

And here is a table of the exercices:

\begin{tabular}{|c | c|}
\hline
Number & tile \\
\ref{exo:first_degree} & \nameref{exo:first_degree}\\
\ref{exo:second_degree} &\nameref{exo:second_degree}\\
\ref{exo:other_exercise} &\nameref{exo:other_exercise}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There might be an easier solution using a `theorem` environment and building a list of theorems - search that on this site for some ideas.

Comment: Try setting \@currentlabelname to #1 right after \refstepcounter.

Comment: @EthanBolker Harish Kumar deleted the answer and so it and the comments are hidden for most purposes.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exo}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{exo}[1]%
{\refstepcounter{exo}%
\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}% addition here
\vspace{0.5cm}\noindent
{\large\bfseries{Exercice \theexo~: #1} \par}
{\par\vspace{0.5cm}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A small example

\section{First degree}
\begin{exo}{First degree equation}\label{exo:first_degree}
Solve the equation~:\[ x+7 = -9 \: . \]
\end{exo}

\section{Second degree}
A little harder\ldots

\begin{exo}{Second degree equation}\label{exo:second_degree}
solve the equation~:\[ x^2 - 2x -3 =0 \: . \]
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{Another exercise}\label{exo:other_exercise}
solve this equation:\[ -3x^2 +7x-64=0 \: .\]
\end{exo}

And here is a table of the exercices:

\begin{tabular}{|c | c|}
\hline
Number & tile \\
\ref{exo:first_degree} & \nameref{exo:first_degree}\\
\ref{exo:second_degree} &\nameref{exo:second_degree}\\
\ref{exo:other_exercise} &\nameref{exo:other_exercise}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Typically (and I'm referring to how `\label`s are done in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)) one would use `\protected@edef\@currentlabelname`.

Comment: @Werner - No problem. Is \protected@edef documented anywhere?

Comment: See p 31 of [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

Comment: Note that `{\begin{large}...\end{large}}\par` is very wrong: it should be `{\large...\par}`